# If a space $X$ has no isolated points, then nor does any dense subset of $X$.

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a topological space with no special properties.

If a space $X$ has no isolated points, then show the same for any dense subset of

$X$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about $X=\{a,b,c\}$, with open sets $\varnothing, \{a,b\}, \{a,b,c\}$, and dense subset $\{a,c\}$?  Should there be an assumption that the space is Hausdorff or something?

Comment: So (to make sure I understand correctly) in your example, $X$ has no isolated points (as isolated points of $X$ are open as singletons), but $a$ is an isolated point of $\{a,c\}$? If this is correct, then there is a mistake in my book (Dugundji).

Comment: That's the idea of the example, yeah.  But some books have special conventions, like a standing assumption that all topological spaces are Hausdorff, in which case this example wouldn't fly.

Comment: Ok thanks. Though in fact in this case, the Hausdorff axiom isn't mentioned at all for another 40 pages.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk: why do you need the point $c$? Any topological space with the indiscrete topology should do, with the dense subspace being any one single element.

Comment: @user225318 : Yes, that's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is true assuming the $T_0$ (Kolmogorov) axiom.

Let $S\subseteq X$ be dense. And suppose $x_0\in S$ is isolated. Then there exists an open set $X_0\ni x_0$ such that $X_0 \cap S = \{x_0\}$. Let $x_1\in X_0$ and $N$ be an open neighbourhood of $x_1$. Suppose $x_0 \not\in N$, then $N \cap X_0 \subset X_0\setminus \{x_0\}$ is open, contradicting density of $S$. Therefore $x_0$ must be in every neighbourhood of $x_1$.

Therefore in $T_0$ holds $x_0$ is isolated in $X$

(The OP may want to check whether $T_0$ is a standing assumption in the book. It is even more reasonable to assume that than assuming Hausdorff.)

---

Editor's note: The above proof actually assumes $T_1$, see YCor's comment below for what went wrong and a counterexample. (I'm leaving this note as the answerer is currently unregistered)

Comment: This is not true. Consider a topology on $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ for which the closed subsets are the whose set, and the $\{0,\dots,n\}$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$. It has no isolated point. But $\{\infty\}$ is a dense subset.

Comment: The first paragraph shows that if $X$ is any topological space $S$ is dense, and $x_0\in S$ is isolated in $S$, then the closure of $\{x_0\}$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$. This is correct. The second paragraph asserts that this implies that $x_0$ is isolated is one assumes $T_0$. This is not correct, you seem to assume $T_1$.